# How can I set up Cocoa style keyboard shortcuts in Mac Terminal.app?

Tags: cocoa, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I love cocoa style keyboard shortcuts and am constantly frustrated that Terminal doesn't behave in the same way.  Does anyone know how to set common cocoa-style keyboard shortcuts in Terminal.app?

I found a blog post that describes how to do this in iTerm: http://blog.jcoffin.com/2008/12/06/mac-keyboard-shortcuts-iterm/. However, I like Terminal.app better for a number of reasons.

Terminal.app allows you to define custom keyboard shortcuts, but it doesn't let you use the command key.  It also doesn't let you define a key for "delete", but for some reason allows "forward delete" (?).

The main ones I want are:

- <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> for moving the cursor a full word
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> for moving to the start/end of a line
- <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> for deleting a full word
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> for deleting a line

If I could just have these I would be happy :-)

Comment: belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: those voting to close, you would probably be surprised that this is a basic software developer knowledge, not sure why would you close it ...

Comment: stefanB: Just because programmers are likely to know how to configure Terminal does not make it a programming question.

Comment: In my job as software developer it is important to know how to setup your development environment, software development is so much more then just type code into a text editor ... I guess that comes with more experience ...

Answer (score 3):

I followed the instructions [in this blog post](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/word-movement-in-terminal/) from Allan Odgaard (of TextMate fame) to set up:

- opt-arrow for word-movement
- ctrl-arrow for moving to start/end of the line (though, to be honest, I end up using ctrl-a and ctrl-e much more often)
- forward-delete (based on [this comment](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/word-movement-in-terminal/#comment-740) which says to map it to ctrl-opt-d)

You can also check the "Use option as meta key" item to get opt-delete to perform word-deletion.

Unfortunately, as Allan says, you cannot bind to the normal delete key, nor can you use the Command key as a modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ones from Unix terminal (shell), I think they work the same in Terminal app:

- full word forward:     <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- full word backward:    <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- end of the line:       <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
- beginning of the line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- delete full word (cursor at the end of the word): <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (Mac <kbd>Del</kbd>?)
- delete the whole command line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>